# Extract namespace

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

I am new to dataweave 2.0. I need help extracting an xml like below payload.

payload

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<ns:test xmlns:ns="http//sample">
  <test1 xmlns:ns1="http://sample1" ns1:firstKey="1234" secondKey="678" thirdKey="456"/>
</ns:test>
```

Need to Get:
1234.

What I tried:
Dataweave Script

```
%dw 2.0
output application/xml
---
payload.test.test1.@firstKey
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have done is correct, however since you are outputting it as application/xml, you would need a root element. So something like this:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/xml
---
{
    a: payload.test.test1.@firstKey
}
```

However if you change your script output to application/json, it would work just fine.

[image]